# generators, promises and co or then-yield

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, generator

I am writing a nodejs program and need to get some config data during initialization time so i can instantiate a singleton. The config data comes back as a promise, which means I have to initialise things on the fly, rather than at require time so i can `module.exports = () => return new blah(config)`. I dont want a factory to return a thenable - I want it to return a new instance of a constructor.

I have an internal library that gets configuration data and returns a promise. I'm trying to use `co` or `then-yield` or a similar library so that I can treat things as if they are synchronous (i *think* this is what these libs are for, but perhaps my understanding is flawed), mostly so I can make a factory that returns an instance, and doesn't return an promise that resolves with the instance

simplified code:

config reader:

```
var read = function () {
  let c = projectConfig.load(); //returns a promise that resolves with config data
  return c;
});

module.exports = {read};
```

factory:

```
let factory = ty.async(function * factory () {
  let cfg = yield configHelper.read();
  console.log('config', cfg)
  return new Constructor(cfg);
})

module.exports = () => factory()
```

index:

```
let factory = require('factory')()
console.log(factory)
```

When I run the program I get the following output

```
Promise {
    _d: {
        p: [Circular],
        c: [],
        a: undefined,
        s: 0,
        d: false,
        v: { cdn: [Object] },
        h: false,
        n: false
    }
} // this is from the main module

config { /* correct config object data here */ } //this is from factory
```

looking at various blog posts talking about this, I would expect that by using then-yield or co, `factory` should return the Constructor with the correct config params. but it looks like it co or ty is doing nothing, and im getting the yield result.

What have i misunderstood?

Comment: No, that's not how `co` etc work. You cannot overcome asynchrony, the result will never be available immediately (synchronously returnable), you'll always get a promise back. Your module needs to export a promise, and you'd use `co` where the promise is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What have i misunderstood?

The result of an `async` function will be a Promise only. So you can access the value of the result of an `async` function only with a `then` handler.

In your case,

```
let factory = require('factory')()

factory.then((consObj) => // use the Constructor object)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. I really dont like a factory returning a thenable but without some kind of config service I cant see a way around it.